# 12-Factor: dynamic backend configuration

Tags: 12factor

The default configuration of a backend for a Twelve-Factor App is to put its (network) location in an environment variable, e.g. `DB=mysql://user:pw@host/db_name`.

But what is the recommended way if your backend configuration is more dynamic? In my case the app could use 1 to n backends depending on the environment. My idea is to use a serialization format like JSON and put it in a single variable like

```
DB="{1: 'host:port', 2: 'host:port'}"
```

Is this the preferable way to deal with such a situation or what would be better alternatives?

Comment: This question was asked a while ago - did you come up with a solution that worked well for you?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that is the "preferred" method, but I think it would work.

You will want to document this idiosyncrasy for future developers, and maybe add some verbose errors/logging pointing to misconfigurations in this unusual setup. If you only want to specify one database, for example, it should be clear that it needs to be specified in quasi-JSON style anyway.

---

I think more 12-factor-y, though, would be to set up an intermediate load-balancer between your servers. That way, your app can connect to the load balancer or a single server with very little transparency as to the nature of the underlying service.

So instead of:

```
SetEnv DB {mysql://something@somewhere, mysql://something@somewhereelse}
```

you would have

```
SetEnv DB mysql://something@load-balancer
```

and the load-balancer handles the multiple databases behind the scenes.

---

You could also have a 2-db system, one for reads and one for writes. The reads could be load-balanced and replicate the `master-server`.

```
SetEnv READ_DB  mysql://something@load-balancer
SetEnv WRITE_DB mysql://something@master-server
```

then in a test situation they would use the same connection string:

```
SetEnv READ_DB  mysql://something@load-balancer
SetEnv WRITE_DB $READ_DB  # not sure about syntax here
```

Comment: While this does not fully match my requirements (because sometimes a client need to connect to one server and sometimes to multiple ones) it is still a very good inspiration. I'm tending to use some sort of registry/master server (similar to the load balancer) where each normal server registers itself so the client can use this master server to query the system configuration.

Comment: That sounds like the same thing. The idea is just to put the minimum amount of configuration burden on the web app, and task the backing service with as much of its own configuration as possible.

Comment: Oh, and if you need to have multiple connections because they are different data sets or kinds of database, then they each deserve to be their own backing service with their own config line(s).